# Code algorithms inside React Native project

Tags: javascript, c++, c, algorithm, react-native

I'm new to React Native and the app I'm building needs to run some algorithms. Is there any way to run functions from a lower-level programming language inside the React app?
I need this because the algorithms I'm running are really time-consuming and it would take way too much time to run it in JavaScript.

Is there any way I can run some C/C++ code from inside the App? Or are there any other programming languages that can be run from the app that is faster?

Comment: Google for React Native Data Bridge: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/passing-data-between-native-and-js-using-react-native-bridge-34e783c0b2f8

Comment: Also, start here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro

Comment: Using a language like C would tie you to one specific kind of machine (that is, what used to be a Web app would now only run on Windows, or Mac, or whatever you compiled for). Look into compiling into WebAssembly. And of course, as with all optimization issues, look first at whether you have the right algorithm--that matters much more than the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a React-specific problem. You want to run native c/c++ logic inside a js/typescript program.

Either use assembly script (similar to typescript) or web assembly (convert native c/c++ to wasm which can be imported in any js/typescript environment).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lxnm9a-Yi8&ab_channel=Maniyar

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm